# Set Theory and finite unions

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be the collection of finite unions of sets of the form $(a,b]\cap Q$ where $-\infty\leq a<b\leq \infty$. Does $\phi\in A$?

Comment: Can you find $a<b$ such that $(a, b] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is empty?

Comment: No I can't. That is the problem I have. I am asking this because it has been asked to show that A is an algebra on $Q$. Then definitely the empty set is in A. But I feel it is not.

Comment: Ah.  Then I guess we'll have to allow degenerate unions.  See Andreas' answer.

Answer (score 5):

Remember that $0$ is a finite number.  The union of $0$ of your half-open intervals is the empty set, and I would consider that to be a finite union of half-open intervals.

Comment: Oh, got it. Thanks.